# Implementing a delay without thread usage

Tags: java, multithreading, class, delay

I'm working on a little project where I want to implement a little delay in a loop, but I don't want to use a thread or use another class. Is this possible?

My code looks like this:

```
int random = (int)(Math.random()*15);
int randomloop;

for (i = 0; i < random; i++){
    randomloop = (int)(Math.random()*15);
    nummerlabel.setText(String.valueOf(randomloop)); //showing a number
    //here i would like to implement a little delay, so the number changes every 0.5 seconds
}
```

Comment: So you don't want to use `Thread.sleep(500)`? That is using the _current_ thread, not another one.

Comment: What do you mean by thread usage?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the class `Thread`? `Thread.sleep(500);`

Comment: take a look here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Comment: No, it's not possible to delay the program without using the class `Thread`.

Comment: Basically the answer is: there is no good way to do it without using another class. And just to be precise: the core of clean code ... is to only do ONE thing within a class ... so using another class that takes care of "delaying" is **much** better than inventing something on your own (which I guarantee you will be much less reliable than a simple call to Thread.sleep) and stuffing that into here.

Comment: It's possible to keep looking at the clock until 500 ms are gone, but *don't do it*. It will freeze your program, it will freeze your system,... This is called "active waiting", and it is generally considered to be harmful.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are already using `Math` and `String` I am assuming you are not opposed to using the standard library and you simply want to avoid creating a new thread. In that case, use `Thread.sleep(...)`.

Comment: The simplest way to do that is to use `Timer`/`TimerTask`

Comment: Re _the better way to do something like this..._  Depends on what "something like this" means.  Looks like the OP's goal is not to create a program that prints a new random number every 500 ms.  Looks like the goal is to _learn_ how to write a program that is just barely one step more sophisticated than Hello World.

Comment: @jameslarge yes, that is a good point. I think I will edit the answer to remove my unfounded assumptions about the OP